# Update records on a table based on IDs from another table

Tags: join, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

SALES table

| ID | DATEMODIFIED |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 4/25/2023 |
| 200 | 4/27/2023 |

LINES table

| ID | TRANSACTION | DATEMODIFIED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | *null* |
| 2 | 100 | *null* |
| 3 | 100 | *null* |
| 4 | 200 | *null* |
| 5 | 200 | *null* |

I am not entirely sure on the appropriate way to join to update DATEMODIFED column on LINES table.  The statement needs to update rows on LINES table where TRANSACTION = 100 with 4/25/2023 and TRANSACTION = 200 with 4/27/2023, etc.  Is this correct and most efficient?  There are millions of rows in both tables.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.DATEMODIFIED = b.DATEMODIFIED 
FROM LINE AS a
INNER JOIN SALES AS b ON a.TRANSACTION = b.ID
```

Comment: which database system are you using always tag it correctly

Comment: Snowflake - added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

snowflake has another syntax see [manual](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/update)

```
UPDATE LINE 
SET LINE.DATEMODIFIED = b.DATEMODIFIED 
FROM 
SALES AS b ON LINE.TRANSACTION = b.ID
```